# How to parse all json property into array list android

Tags: android, json

I have this `gist` I created that returns a `json` type.

[Link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benthemobileguy/c5ee9e6e5a5db7e70aeeba4137816073/raw/7df879385a193d1c91cdc63fe341a9ab8a37a7c6/my%2520map)

I want to parse all 'name' properties into an `arrayList` so I can use within a `Spinner`. That means all the values with the 'name' property should be parsed inside an `arrayList`. I already have my `pojo` class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use java 8 Streams. Obv you can do this using a simple for loop as well.

```
List<Features> features = your_pojo.getFeatures();
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
Stream.of(features).map(m -> m.getProperties().getName()).ForEach(f -> names.add(f));
```

names arraylist will contain all the names.

can read about streams here if not familiar - https://stackify.com/streams-guide-java-8/

Comment: am I to use this with an http client like retrofit?

Comment: no, what i meant was, as u mentioned u have a POJO class already, so once you have all the data, just extract names out of that data.